# AWS Lambda reach memory limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

i use this Lambda function to generate thumbnails on the fly. But i get the following error:

```
REPORT RequestId: 9369f148-2a85-11e7-a571-5f1e1818669e Duration: 188.18 ms Billed Duration: 200 ms Memory Size: 1536 MB Max Memory Used: 1536 MB
```

AND...

```
RequestId: 9369f148-2a85-11e7-a571-5f1e1818669e Process exited before completing request
```

So i think i reach the max Memory Limit. Without the function "uploadRecentImage()" it works. But if i add a new size to imgVariants[] i will also hit the Memory Limit. 
I think the way the function handle the imgVariants (each loop) will cause this but i don't know to make it better.
I will be grateful for any help.

Here is my function:

```
// dependencies
var async = require('async');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var gm = require('gm').subClass({
  imageMagick: true
}); // use ImageMagick
var util = require('util');

// configuration as code - add, modify, remove array elements as desired
var imgVariants = [
  {
    "SIZE": "Large1",
    "POSTFIX": "-l",
    "MAX_WIDTH": 6000,
    "MAX_HEIGHT": 6000,
    "SIZING_QUALITY": 75,
    "INTERLACE": "Line"
  },
    {
    "SIZE": "Large1",
    "POSTFIX": "-l",
    "MAX_WIDTH": 1280,
    "MAX_HEIGHT": 1280,
    "SIZING_QUALITY": 75,
    "INTERLACE": "Line"
  },
  {
    "SIZE": "Large1",
    "POSTFIX": "-l",
    "MAX_WIDTH": 500,
    "MAX_HEIGHT": 500,
    "SIZING_QUALITY": 75,
    "INTERLACE": "Line"
  },
    {
    "SIZE": "Large1",
    "POSTFIX": "-l",
    "MAX_WIDTH": 100,
    "MAX_HEIGHT": 100,
    "SIZING_QUALITY": 75,
    "INTERLACE": "Line"
  }
];
var DST_BUCKET_POSTFIX = "resized";



// get reference to S3 client
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = function (event, context) {
  // Read options from the event.
  console.log("Reading options from event:\n", util.inspect(event, {
    depth: 5
  }));
  var srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  // Object key may have spaces or unicode non-ASCII characters.
  var srcKey = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));
  // derive the file name and extension
  var srcFile = srcKey.match(/(.+)\.([^.]+)/);

  var srcName = srcFile[1];
  var scrExt = srcFile[2];
  // set the destination bucket
  var dstBucket = srcBucket + DST_BUCKET_POSTFIX;


  // make sure that source and destination are different buckets.
  if (srcBucket === dstBucket) {
    console.error("Destination bucket must be different from source bucket.");
    return;
  }

  if (!scrExt) {
    console.error('unable to derive file type extension from file key ' + srcKey);
    return;
  }

  if (scrExt != "jpg" && scrExt != "png") {
    console.log('skipping non-supported file type ' + srcKey + ' (must be jpg or png)');
    return;
  }

  function processImage(data, options, callback) {
    gm(data.Body).size(function (err, size) {

      var scalingFactor = Math.min(
        options.MAX_WIDTH / size.width,
        options.MAX_HEIGHT / size.height
      );
      var width = scalingFactor * size.width;
      var height = scalingFactor * size.height;

      this.resize(width, height)
        .quality(options.SIZING_QUALITY || 75)
        .interlace(options.INTERLACE || 'None')
        .toBuffer(scrExt, function (err, buffer) {
          if (err) {
            callback(err);

          } else {
            uploadImage(data.ContentType, buffer, options, callback);
            uploadRecentImage(data.ContentType, buffer, options, callback);
          }
        });
    });
  }

  function uploadImage(contentType, data, options, callback) {
    // Upload the transformed image to the destination S3 bucket.
    s3.putObject({
        Bucket: dstBucket,
        Key: options.MAX_WIDTH + '/' + srcName + '.' + scrExt,
        Body: data,
        ContentType: contentType
      },
      callback);
  }


  function uploadRecentImage(contentType, data, options, callback) {
    if(options.MAX_WIDTH == 500){
         s3.putObject({
            Bucket: dstBucket,
            Key: 'recent_optimized.' + scrExt,
            Body: data,
            ContentType: contentType
          },
          callback);
    }
    if(options.MAX_WIDTH == 100){
           s3.putObject({
            Bucket: dstBucket,
            Key: 'recent_thumb.' + scrExt,
            Body: data,
            ContentType: contentType
          },
          callback);
     }
  }


  // Download the image from S3 and process for each requested image variant.
  async.waterfall(
    [
      function download(next) {
          // Download the image from S3 into a buffer.
          s3.getObject({
              Bucket: srcBucket,
              Key: srcKey
            },
            next);
      },
      function processImages(data, next) {
          async.each(imgVariants, function (variant, next) {
            processImage(data, variant, next);
          }, next);

      }

    ],
    function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(
          'Unable to resize ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
          ' and upload to ' + dstBucket +
          ' due to an error: ' + err
        );
      } else {
        console.log(
          'Successfully resized ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
          ' and uploaded to ' + dstBucket
        );
      }

      context.done();
    }
  );
};
```

Comment: While looping do you really need to keep already processed images in memory? Why not let your source invoke 'lambda' function in loop instead of looping inside lambda?

Comment: If you need 1.5GB to process your thumbnails, you have a big memory leak problem. *Don't* try to process all images at once. *Don't* keep anything in memory unless you have to. Clean up after processing each image. *Don't* use global structures, especially if you want to process images in parallel. Cleaning up is impossible with global structures

Comment: Alternatively, you might consider using "resizing as a service" systems such as [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) and [Imgix](http://imgix.com/).

Answer (score 0):

1. You can limit the number of parallel processImages calls:

Replace `async.each(imgVariants,`

with `async.eachLimit(imgVariants, 2,`

to not process more than two images in parallel.

2. The script has a bug:

`uploadImage(data.ContentType, buffer, options, callback);
uploadRecentImage(data.ContentType, buffer, options, callback);`

This will call `callback` twice which is not allowed. Only call the callback once!

3. The script has another bug: `event.Records[0]` it will only process the first image. If you upload multiple images at the same time this will miss some images.

Comment: 1. But than all imgVariants are processed? Or only the first 2? If i do this i got no Memory error but also no resized Images :-(